# Visual Studio Error unknown type 'array^'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm having a hard time searching for why I'm getting this erorr. I am working on a CLR UI windows form application using C++ on visual studios.

If I try to do

```
private: int valueInSquare[9];
```

I get an error saying " a member of a managed class cannot be a standard array"

If I change it to

```
private: array<int>^valueInSquare;
```

I get an erorr when trying to view the header file design for my form that says,

C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 94, Column: 24 --- Unknown type 'array^'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built.

Here is a portion of the code since a lot of was pre-generated by using the designer on my header file.

```
   #pragma once
#include "Windows.h"

namespace MagicSquare {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MagicSquare
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MagicSquare : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

    public:
        MagicSquare(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MagicSquare()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label8;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label9;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox8;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox9;
    private: array<int>valueInSquare;
    //private: int valueInSquare[9];
    private: bool valueAlreadyUsed;


    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->valueInSquare = gcnew array<int>(9);
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                valueInSquare[i] = 10;
            }

            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(65, 63);
            this->label1->Name = "1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"label1";
            this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(218, 63);
            this->label2->Name = "2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label2->Text = L"label2";
            this->label2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(383, 63);
            this->label3->Name = "3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label3->Text = L"label3";
            this->label3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(65, 153);
            this->label4->Name = "4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 3;
            this->label4->Text = L"label4";
            this->label4->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this->label5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(218, 153);
            this->label5->Name = "5";
            this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label5->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label5->Text = L"label5";
            this->label5->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this->label6->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(383, 153);
            this->label6->Name = "6";
            this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label6->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label6->Text = L"label6";
            this->label6->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // label7
            // 
            this->label7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(65, 242);
            this->label7->Name = "7";
            this->label7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label7->TabIndex = 6;
            this->label7->Text = L"label7";
            this->label7->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // label8
            // 
            this->label8->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(218, 242);
            this->label8->Name = "8";
            this->label8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label8->TabIndex = 7;
            this->label8->Text = L"label8";
            this->label8->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // label9
            // 
            this->label9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            this->label9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(383, 242);
            this->label9->Name = "9";
            this->label9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 65);
            this->label9->TabIndex = 8;
            this->label9->Text = L"label9";
            this->label9->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::labelOnClick);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(65, 84);
            this->textBox1->Name = "1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 9;
            this->textBox1->Visible = false;
            this->textBox1->KeyPress += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::MagicSquare::textBoxOnKeyPressed);
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(218, 84);
            this->textBox2->Name = "2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 10;
            this->textBox2->Visible = false;
            this->textBox2->KeyPress += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::MagicSquare::textBoxOnKeyPressed);
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(383, 84);
            this->textBox3->Name = "3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 20);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 11;
            this->textBox3->Visible = false;
            this->textBox3->KeyPress += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler(this, &MagicSquare::MagicSquare::textBoxOnKeyPressed);
            // 
            // textBox4
            //
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "managed classes" in C++, and `private: array<int>^valueInSquare;` is syntactically invalid, too. Please change the language tag from [c++] to the dialect you are actually using, like C++/CLI.

Comment: You have a caret between `array<int>` and `valueInSquare;`

Comment: @BaummitAugen my bad, my professor usually says Visual C++ it is the first time that I am working with the language so I thought that is what I was  working with

Comment: @SidS removing the caret says "C++/CLI array type is not allowed here" Is there a way to define an array in visual c++?

Comment: Visual C++ is not a language either, it's an IDE or compiler. You should really figure out what language you are using, otherwise, asking a useful question might prove to be difficult.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Actually, could it be, because this code is located in the .h header file for my windows form? I'll post all of it if that will help

Comment: Given I don't know the Microsoft C++ dialects in detail I'm not sure, but the caret hints C++/CLI. You should be able to figure that out from whatever learning resource you are working with though.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a name conflict on the identifier `array`.  Try using its fully-qualified name `cli::array`, to avoid ambiguity with `std::array` and other usages of the name.